# Multiple function graphs in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 2 functions, each of which produces a graph. I'm trying to put them both in 1 function, but it only outputs 1 of the 2 graphs (the graph from whichever function is written last). My code looks like this:

```
function [ output_args ] = Function3( input_args )
    Function1;
    Function2; 

end
```

Answer (score 2):

`Function2` is overwriting to the figure. So, the plot of `Function1` is lost.

You can just write `figure;` between the `Function1` and `Function2` lines if you want them in seperate windows.

Or if you want them in one window you can use `subplot`. Like this:

```
subplot(2,1,2);
Function1;
subplot(2,2,2);
Function2;
```

Comment: From the question the OP is _"trying to put them both in 1 function"_. I suppose this means he wants them both in the same graph, so `figure` is not what he wants.

Comment: @EitanT I think the OP means `Function3`.

Comment: Ah, well then, you deserve +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it works

```
           function [ output_args ] = Function3( input_args )
                figure, hold
                Function1;
                figure(1)
                Function2; 
           end
```

use hold function in proper place